# The check with the module in the loop doesn`t work

Tags: c++

There is a task. It is necessary in a one-dimensional array of N real numbers to calculate the number of the maximum modulo element among unpaired numbers.
I wrote the code, but it does not work. I can’t understand what’s wrong with him.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");
    const int KolEl = 5; 
    int mas[KolEl];
    int max = abs(mas[0]);
    int result;

    for (int i = 0; i < KolEl; i++)
    {
        cout << " Введите елемент[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> mas[i];
        if (mas[i] % 2 == 1) {
            if (abs(mas[i]) > max) {
                result = i;
                cout << result << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `int max = abs(mas[0]);` what do you think the value in `max` will be after this line?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know :D

Comment: It'll be garbage / indeterminate / Undefined Behaviour, since you never initialized your array. You just create an array that can hold 5 values, put nothing in it, then read the first (uninitialised) value. And you expect a sane result *why*?

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debuggin your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize `max` as:

```
int mas[KolEl];
int max = abs(mas[0]);
```

However, the values in `mas[]` are garbage values (read: undefined behavior). So now the value in `max` is also UB.

You then go on to use that value to compare to the input you take:

```
if (abs(mas[i]) > max) {
```

So the result of that comparison is undefined.

You probably meant to declare `max` as something like:

```
int max = INT_MIN;
```

So that the first comparison will always be true (every int except `INT_MIN` will be greater than it).

Comment: Your answer helped me solve my problem. Now everything is working correctly. Thanks.